# Impossible to format a 4GB RAW usb flash drive

Tags: partitioning, usb, flash, usb-drive

I have 4GB usb flashdrive I tried to format with Widows 7 and couldn't format it any way I tried with Kali Linux (a pentesting Debian distro) to format my RAW usb flash drive (as detected on Windows 7) when I try to format it with GParted to fat32 it says `Input/outpout error during write on dev/sdf` I did Retry but it took a very very long time trying to format so I aborted the operation than I tried `dd if=/dev/sdf1 of=~/flashdrive.img` but this

```
dd: reading `/dev/sdf1': Input/output error
12776+0 records in
12776+0 records out
6541312 bytes (6.5 MB) copied, 649.385 s, 10.1 kB/s
```

please how to fix the flashdrive?
Thank you very much

Comment: I had the same problem once before, with a 4GB flash drive as well. It was detected as RAW in Windows, just like yours. In Ubuntu, it would also give me that `Input/output` error, just like yours. I tried **everything** to bring it back to life. Formatting. Writing with zeros, ones and random. "Low level formatting" tools. Everything. But it never came to life. I threw it in the dumpster =/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That flash drive is most likely busted. If you want to see all the errors do ...

```
dd if=/dev/sdf1  of=~/flashdrive.img conv=noerror,sync
```

The terminal probably can not buffer all the errors you get.

- [ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/) might be an option.